# Long term data saving in assembly 8086

Tags: database, variables, assembly, tasm

I am building a school project in assembly 8086, and it’s some kind of library management program, which you can choose your library, add customers to your list, add books and more. I am trying to save my data for long term using txt files but I don’t know how to make it most efficient. Is there another way to save my data in assembly? Like database or XML?

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably "too broad" for SO, but I will still "answer" it, because in comments it would get too crowded, need some formatting for this one.

> to make it most efficient

In what way most efficient?

For smallest size on disk you can use some compression, but that will hurt performance (and also it's not trivial to code it, especially in 16 bit 8086 real mode with limited amount of memory, any modern compression scheme would be pain or underperform, as they often need tens-hundreds of mega bytes of memory to build up dictionary tables/etc).

For performance and code simplicity you may probably rather design your own custom binary file format, dumping memory state to disk and reloading it as such, with some good memory structures for data and making the data occupy consecutive blocks of memory, dumping/reading the whole block is simplest to code, and will perform reasonably.

For easiest data checking and further re-usability of data some kind of TXT/json/XML file format would be better, so even human can read/modify the stored data outside of your code, but this will require more coding, some code to format current binary data in memory into the textual representation, which gets written to disk, and some parser to read such textual data back and convert them into the binary structures/values in the memory.

I find XML pointlessly verbose and being both ineffectively large (when compared to binary data), and still difficult to edit by human, as the XML tags require lot of writing, whenever it makes sense, I prefer JSON over XML, as it is a bit simpler to write it by hand in pure text editor without any assist, and it's a bit simpler to read. But there are situations where XML makes lot more sense, as it's slightly different thing. In case of data dump like you are asking for, I guess having custom TXT file (with some custom formatting rules, how to create the structure of data) or JSON is enough, I don't see where XML would bring something helpful to it.

Maybe start with the binary dump+reload of whole data structure from memory, as that should be easiest to code, then try to write by hand few TXT files to see if you can figure out some nice way how to structure the data, and try to write then formatter-writer and parser for such data.

As your target platform is DOS I guess (from the "8086" limit), there are just OS services to write/read certain amount of bytes to/from file. No formatting/processing whatsoever is provided by DOS, so everything around TXT/XML/database/... is up to you and your code. You can read/write block of bytes with DOS services, anything above that must be programmed by you. (or you can try to find some library, but as that technology is now like 20+ years dead and obsolete... good luck)

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful